# How to make throwing KeyError when slicing Pandas Dataframe by index?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've been slicing `Pandas.dataframe` by index through
`df.loc[date_start:date_end]` but found that `df.loc` didn't throw the `KeyError` even if the `date_end` is out of boudary of the `df`, and this is because of the enlargement of the method, `loc`.

Then, what is the most clear way to slicing the dataframe by index and make throwing KeyError if the index is out of boundary? My `df` is as below.

```
                     my_value       
open_time
2019-12-01 00:00:00  0.04032 
2019-12-01 00:10:00  0.04010 
...                      ...   
2020-01-01 23:40:00  0.04897  
2020-01-01 23:50:00  0.04883 
2020-01-01 00:00:00  0.04897
```

Comment: df.resample('7D').sum() You can use this `resample`.

Comment: @r-beginners what does resampling to weekly data have to do with KeyErrors?

Comment: The ''7D'' is just an example, which means that it can be used if the extraction condition is a certain interval.

Comment: @r-beginners I don't clearly understand what you're saying. So how could I make throwing KeyError when I put the `date_end` as `datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 12, 0, 0)` which is far from the maximum date of my `df` using `resample`?

Comment: I think the easiest way might be `if date_end not in df.index: raise KeyError`.

Comment: Or, since the OP is using a slice, `if date_end > df.index.max(): raise KeyError`

Comment: I wonder if there's another function so that I could handle the error without the additional 'condition statement', but I searched a lot and there's no such thing I believe. Thanks! Both ways are nice :)